# Why I'm getting Gradle error if I follow the guide in Flutter?

Tags: android-studio, flutter, bundle

I've tried to export the app bundle from Flutter, the problem is at the signingConfig, default is debug (and it works) but if I make release shows Gradle error and can't go. What are the steps or where I'm wrong if I followed the Flutter release guide?

I have created buildTypes but still getting error even if I select debug version.

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 29

lintOptions {
    disable 'InvalidPackage'
    checkReleaseBuilds false
}

defaultConfig {
    // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
    applicationId "com.homework.practice1"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 29
    ndk.abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a','arm64-v8a','x86','x86_64'
    versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
    versionName flutterVersionName
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}


signingConfigs {
    release {
        keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
        keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
        storeFile file(keystoreProperties['storeFile'])
        storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
    }
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }
}
```

I expect to export the 32 and 64 bits app bundle, but when I go with the debug signing it's only one. And if a select to release makes Gradle error 1.

Comment: if this is the complete gradle file then looks like you are missing a declaration of `keystoreProperties`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could add this code, in build.gradle, after "flutter", as I indicated below, this will generate a 32-bit and 64-bit app when you generate the "build",

```
flutter {
    source '../..'
}

afterEvaluate {
    mergeReleaseJniLibFolders.doLast {
        def archTypes = ["arm-release", "arm64-release"]
        archTypes.forEach { item ->
            copy {
                from zipTree("$flutterRoot/bin/cache/artifacts/engine/android-$item/flutter.jar")
                include 'lib/*/libflutter.so'
                into "$buildDir/intermediates/jniLibs/release/"
                eachFile {
                    it.path = it.path.replaceFirst("lib/", "")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this, but still not working. I got the error ProcessException: Process "/android/gradlew" exited abnormally:
 Command: /android/gradlew app:properties

Comment: You could do a "Flutter clean" and then try to create a file "key.properties", located in "/android/key.properties", in this file it is declared: storePassword, keyPassword, keyAlias, and storeFile.